# CakePHP short permalinks?

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, permalinks

Currently I'm developing an application with CakePHP and I want to change links. In default operation links works like:

website.com/**controller**/***method***/***argument-what-we-want***

because of MVC structure but, I want to change this link and I want to make appear links like:

website.com/**shows**/***walking-dead***

What am I have to do to make links something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either call your controller **shows** and your action **walking-dead**, Or you can add a new route in routes.php

```
Router::connect('/shows/walking-dead', array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'method', 'argument-what-we-want'));
```

The first paremeter in connect() even supports wild cards (*)

**EDIT**

If at the moment your URLs look like **/shows/view/walking-dead**

You can add a new route like:

```
Router::connect('/shows/*', array('controller' => 'shows', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Which will let you use this URL: **/shows/walking-dead**

Comment: but walking-dead part will change dynamically depends on data comes from database. I mean walkind-dead part can't be a method. shows has to be a method walking-dead must be an argument of shows method. I don't want to see controller name on links...

Comment: And where should I make this route? in which file?